# Como utilizar a estrutura de repetição 'enquanto'? dúvidas em um exercício especifico

Tags: visualg

Preciso elaborar um algoritmo referente a "Pedido de Compras". Onde fica a disposição do usuário escrever o nome do produto e seu valor e quantidade, e ao final o código apresenta o resultado da multiplicação (preço unitário*quantidade).
Porém, o meu código da errado e estou em dúvida como resolver. (Sou iniciante no ramo da programação)

O código que criei, onde está o erro?

```
Var
produto,totalPedido,precoUnit:real
quant:inteiro
i:inteiro
Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
enquanto (i <> N) faca  
escreva("Produto: ")
  leia(produto)
  escreva("Preço unitário: ")
  leia(precoUnit)
  escreva("Quantidade: ")
  leia(quant)
fimenquanto
  totalPedido <- precoUnit * quant
  escreva("Total de pedidos: R$",totalPedido)
Fimalgoritmo
```

[image: o resultado tem que ser esse - feito no visualg]

***O resultado tem que ser esse***

vlw pela ajuda :)

Answer (score -1):

Presumindo que você queira calcular o total para N produtos, use:

```
Var
    produto, totalPedido, precoUnit: real
    quant, i, N: inteiro
Inicio
    escreva("Informe a quantidade de produtos: ")
    leia(N)
    i <- 0
    totalPedido <- 0
    enquanto (i < N) faca  
        escreva("Produto: ")
        leia(produto)
        escreva("Preço unitário: ")
        leia(precoUnit)
        escreva("Quantidade: ")
        leia(quant)
        totalPedido <- totalPedido + precoUnit * quant
        i <- i + 1
    fimenquanto
    escreva("Total de pedidos: R$ ", totalPedido)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Para uma saída como apresentada na imagem:

```
Var
    produto, totalPedido, precoUnit: real
    quant: inteiro
    continua: caractere
Inicio
    continua <- "S"
    totalPedido <- 0
    enquanto (continua = "S" ou continua = "s") faca  
        escreva("Produto: ")
        leia(produto)
        escreva("Preço unitário: ")
        leia(precoUnit)
        escreva("Quantidade: ")
        leia(quant)
        totalPedido <- totalPedido + precoUnit * quant
        escreval("----------------")
        escreva("Continua ?(S/N) ")
        leia(continua)
    fimenquanto
    escreva("Total do pedido: R$ ", totalPedido)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Esse seu segundo código me ajudou bastante. Apenas algo que tive que alterar para funcionar corretamente: linha 8 -        ***enquanto (continua = "S") ou (continua = "s") faca***        Apenas isso para que funcionasse. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Estou em dúvida se o VisuAlg diferencia letras maiúsculas de minúsculas nesse tipo de comparação. Faça um teste.